# Deleting Core Data objects from in-memory store turns them into faults but does not erase them

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data

I have a Core Data stack based on the `NSInMemoryStoreType` store. And I've noticed that deleting objects doesn't really remove them or make them nil, bur rather simply turns them into faults.

For example, *(MyManagedObjectEntityClass as well as the <> identifier are placeholders)*:

```
    MyManagedObjectEntityClass *o = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"<MyManagedObjectEntityClass Entity Name>" inManagedObjectContext:self.localContext];
    NSLog(@"\n%@", o);
    [self.localContext deleteObject:o];
    NSLog(@"\n%@", o);
```

Will log that the object is still there only that it's data is a fault.

And adding         `[self.localContext save:nil];` after the delete doesn't change this either.

I was hoping I could at some point test the `o` variable for `nil`, in which case I'd reload the object - but it seems I can't.

Just in case, yes, I know I could instead test `o` for `-isFault`. But thing is, extrapolate this test to an NSSet and I can't just rely on `[[set anyObject] isFault]` to conclude that all objects in that set have been removed (Ideally the set's count would be 0, but all objects are still there as faults).

So I'm wondering if it's possible at all or what alternate approach could I take to be able to test that objects have been deleted in a way transparent to the fact that they are managed objects.

Comment: have you tried testing with `[o isDeleted]`?

Comment: Thing is that puts me in the same boat as isFault. The objects themselves are deleted from the context. If I do a fetch request after the delete the context returns no matches. The problem is really that any references to the objects kept in client code (an NSArray in a view controller, for instance, holding a bunch of managed objects) are still in the collection after deleting and even though they are faults they are still objects if I test against nil or test the collection's count.

Comment: It might be that the way I'm trying to use the managed objects is just outside the scope of core data. I was thinking maybe writing a category or subclassing the collections to make them aware of managed objects but it might be super inefficient.

Comment: Read [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002320-SW10) about could not fulfill faults

Comment: My problem is actually a combination of C semantics (by value) and the conditions and behaviour of core data you just linked it. Thanks for the pointer! (no pun intended)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not actually a Core Data issue. C (and by extension Objective-C) doesn't work like that.

The `deleteObject:` method takes one argument, a pointer to an object. It can change the object (like setting its `isDeleted` flag), or it can do other things related to the object (like deleting it from its managed object context). It *cannot* change the value of the pointer itself. So whatever it does or should do, C says that once it's done, the pointer that you pass in still points to the same location in memory. As a result it's actually impossible for that method to force that pointer to be nil in this language. If you want it to be nil, you have to change that yourself. (As an aside, it would have been possible to implement the method to take a pointer to pointer argument, which *could* modify your pointer. This would have no effect on other references such as those in arrays, though, so it would be kind of pointless).

This is why the `isDeleted` method is public, so that if you have a pointer to this object in some other location, you can check whether it has been deleted before attempting to use it.

If that's not convenient enough (and it often isn't), Core Data also provides `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` and `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`. You can use these anywhere in your app to get notified of changes to the context and respond in whatever way is appropriate (updating an array, for example). These notifications both try to help you out by providing lists of inserted, updated, and deleted objects. Use those when possible to check whether you actually need to update your references.

Comment: I know the difference between C/obj-C vs C++ semantics. But I guess I was thinking about it in terms of an oldschool C array kind of thing. Something along the lines of `typedef struct {
     int num;
   } obj;
   
   int main() {
     obj* a[3];
     a[0] = malloc(sizeof(obj));
     a[0]->num = 55;
  
     printf("\n%p", a[0]);
     free(a[0]);
     a[0] = NULL;
     printf("\n%p", a[0]);
  
     return 0;
  }`. Thanks!